# Disabling OnClick action for lightbox blog featured image

Tags: javascript, onclick, lightbox

I'd like to disable the lightbox pop up for the featured images on both my blog and tutorials landing pages.

Best case scenario, the photo would link to the article but if not, I'm happy with it just not being clickable at all. I'm not good at javascript and have researched enough to know it's on the onclick action I need to disable but can't successfully figure out how to apply it to my required pages.

Could anyone please help me with the correct code(s)? Any help is greatly appreciated!

The pages I'm trying to disable this function on are 
https://katiakolour.com/tutorials/
https://katiakolour.com/blog/

Answer (score 0):

But your links are pointing to images.

Obviously, changing `href` attribute of your links from images to articles would make more sense than "Disabling OnClick action".